# Find a supplier that supplies a unique product

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a master list of sales. Each record contains a product name and the supplier of each product. In some cases the same product could be sold by many suppliers, but the master record only lists the supplier who provided the product for that particular sale.

What I need to do is find all products where a specific supplier is the only supplier to ever provide that product.

For example, today's master sales list looks like:

```
Product                     Supplier
---------------------------------------------
A4 Steering Wheel           Audi
Brembo Brake Pads           Top Parts
Brembo Brake Disks          Brakes Direct
Recaro Sports Seat          Performance Pts
Brembo Brake Pads           Performance Pts
Brembo Brake Disks          Brakes Direct
A4 sump nut                 Audi
Recaro Sports Seat          Top Parts
```

In the above sample I'm only interested in the A4 Products because they are sold directly by Audi. The Brembo and Recaro products are sold by multiple suppliers so I want to ignore them. How can I find all of the products sold where Audi are the only supplier?

My SQL skills are very rusty so I don't really have any attempts worth showing, I've come nowhere close to extracting what I want! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```
SELECT Product, MIN(Supplier)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Your example dataset did not contain duplicates, but if your real dataset does or contains additional unique columns like a timestamp you can also qualify on `DISTINCT` suppliers.

```
SELECT Product, MIN(Supplier)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Supplier) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Derrick, I had marked GMB's answer correct because it worked for my specific case now, but your answer is actually more correct for where I am working with a much bigger dataset with unknown unique suppliers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select ms.*
from master_sales ms
where 
    ms.supplier = 'Audi'
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from master_sales ms1 
        where ms1.product = ms.product and ms1.supplier <> ms.supplier
    )
```

Another option is aggregation:

```
select product
from master_sales
group by product
having 
    max(case when supplier = 'Audi' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when supplier <> 'Audi' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't believe the OP is trying to filter on 'Audi'. I believe they want 'Audi' in their result set because it's unique.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller: yes I think that you are right, seeing OP's comment on the accepted answer;